# Wine Not Working ! Error : Invalid directory prefix32 in WINEPREFIX: not an absolute path

Tags: wine, winetricks

I am using 64-Bit Linux, and when I Try to open an exe file from command line by the command `wine somefile.exe` I get an error which says:

```
wine: invalid directory prefix32 in WINEPREFIX: not an absolute path
```

Now, I tried to Debug that. In my root/ directory, there is already a folder called `prefix32/` which contains these files:

```
dosdevices  drive_c  system.reg  userdef.reg  user.reg
```

Moreover, I also went to my Wine Folder by `root/.wine` Which contains files

```
dosdevices  drive_c  system.reg  userdef.reg  user.reg  winetricks.log
```

I also checked `nano cat /etc/environment` but it is currently empty. Now, I am actually clueless about how to debug this.

Running `echo $WINEPREFIX` gives me `prefix32`.

Comment: Run `echo $WINEPREFIX` and edit your question with the output.

Comment: Edited @ThomasW.

Comment: and I've provided an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact error is self-explanatory: the `WINEPREFIX` environment variable needs to be an absolute path to the wine prefix.

Based on your `echo $WINEPREFIX`, it is only set to `prefix32` which is going to be a relative path to your current directory.

If you know that your wine prefix is always going to be `prefix32` then edit your `~/.bashrc` to do this at the end:

```
export WINEPREFIX="/home/$USER/prefix32"
```

If you only need it to use that prefix temporarily, then put it in front of your `wine` command:

```
WINEPREFIX=/home/$USER/prefix32 wine somefile.exe
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the Information, I just edited my `~/.bashrc` and wrote `export WINEPREFIX="/home/$USER/prefix32"` as per your Instructions. Now, When i Try to Open Any .exe File Using the Command `wine somefile.exe` It Leaves me Error `wine: '/root/.wine' is a 64-bit installation, it cannot be used with a 32-bit wineserver.`

Comment: Are you trying to run Wine as root?  Because that uses the root user's wineprefix, NOT your own.  Why in the heck are yo utrying to use Wine as root?  (Security 101: DO NOT RUN THINGS AS ROOT UNLESS THERE IS NO OTHER OPTION)